# How to copy a JOB, PROGRAM, SCHEDULE definition to run it in another Oracle 11g DB?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, database-administration

I need to copy some Jobs, Schedules and Programs from an Oracle 11g DB to another one, but when I try to look for the SQL of the Job/Schedule/Program on SQL Developer 4.1.3, the SQL tab shows nothing on Edit mode.

When I open a table and I click on the SQL tab, the SQL for create the table is showed up. I was expecting a similar behavior for a Job/Schedule/Program.

How can I copy a JOB/PROGRAM/SCHEDULE definition to run it in another Oracle 11g DB?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The easiest way for Jobs is to use `DBMS_METADATA`:

```
select dbms_metadata.get_ddl('PROCOBJ', job_name) 
from user_scheduler_jobs;
```

I'm not 100% sure about schedules / programs, though.

Comment: Thanks!!! That works for JOB, PROGRAM and SCHEDULE. For some reason I get 2 rows with the same information but works.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can also use expdp utility and use `include=PROCOBJ`. All schedules are objects type PROCOBJ. The you should have all jobs which are owned by schema you are exporting. (If you want DDL you can use impdp with `sqlfile=` to write dump into SQL file. Or use method suggested by Frank Schmitt)

Unfortunately I think if you use this method or method suggested by Frank Schmitt I think you won't be able to get schedules owned by SYS.